# Alternative to R View() in server environment with no X11

Tags: r

I work with R in a linux server and would like to have a functionality similar to View() in RStudio where you can look at your dataset in a tabular format.

The problem is I will not have x11 enabled, this is not an option.

Is there any good alternative way?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11551/is-there-a-good-browser-viewer-to-see-an-r-dataset-rda-file may you will get some good ideas.

Comment: @Alice thanks for the link, I will try all this solutions out and report back as to what what worked best for me.

Comment: Is running headless RStudio an option for you? I’ve never done it myself but by all accounts it works very well.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the package `tableHTML` which produces an HTML table that can be seen in the viewer and/or browser.

It is fairly easy to use, all you need to to is:

```
library(tableHTML)

tableHTML(mtcars, rownames = FALSE, theme = 'scientific')
```

This returns:

[image: tableHTML_mtcars]

Comment: nice answer but in View() you can also SORT columns

Comment: @AndreElrico Without X, implementing a feature like that could be quite hard. Of-course, nothing is keeping you from sorting the table before passing it to `tableHTML()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [clemens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765466/2706569) but produces searchable and sortable output:

Use a [parameterized report](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html) and knit it to HTML using `rmarkdown::render`. The resulting HTML file is opened in the default browser.

- Create `view_template.Rmd` in your working directory with the following contents:

````
---
params:
  myinput: ""
---

```{r, echo = FALSE} 
DT::datatable(params$myinput, options = list(pageLength = 20))
```
````

- To view a data set, run `browseURL(rmarkdown::render(input = "view_template.Rmd", params = list(myinput = iris)))`, replacing `iris` by whichever data set is to be shown.

Of course, this could be wrapped in a nice helper function to get code that is better readable and easier to (re-) use. You need to install the packages `DT` and `rmarkdown` before running the code.

Tested on Windows 10; hopefully passing a file path to `browseURL` works on Linux as well.

---

Output:

[image: Sample output]

Comment: I have to admit that I don't know much about Linux. If "I will not have x11 enabled" implies "cannot open a browser", then … well, the generated HTML could still be rendered on another system.