# Easily view/browse free-text datasets in R/RStudio - alternatives to View() in R/RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

When working with survey data (10-30 columns, 100 - 10k rows, mix of demographic columns like name, age etc, and free-text responses up to `nchar == 3000`), `View()` isn't so useful, because it only displays the first 50 or so characters of lengthy strings (we can always widen the column, but this has practical limitations). AFAIK, increasing row height is not possible. So it is not easy to view free text inside RStudio unless it's in the console, which is not necessarily designed for easily browsing through columns of long strings.

Is there any function like `View()` that displays data similarly but allows for resizing of row heights (to display >1 line of long strings), and perhaps some smarts to allow us to explore list columns in data.frames?

One idea is a function that takes a data.frame argument, writes it as a temp file, and starts a shiny app that displays the data. But something in native R (or built into RStudio) would probably be better than an ad hoc shiny app.

Note: I *do* know how to achieve this in markdown using `kableextra` and similar packages that make nice bootstrap tables. However, the goal is to reduce friction between coding in the script pane in RStudio and exploring the data, and I feel like moving code into an `Rmd` has potential but creates extra friction

Comment: Primitive, but useful tool [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765466/5783745)

Comment: You can use DT without building up a whole app. Is the idea to check on your data after doing some manipulation?

Comment: @Phil basically I just want to look over and read the data, and be able to quickly/easily flick back and forth from the data and to coding (writing the data and using an external program achieves the goal but very inefficiently because of the extra steps of writing/tabbing to the other program). But `View()` is imperfect to say the least. So yep, to manipulate, check, manipulate, check. I hope to find/make a way where it is a 'comfortable' reading experience (as opposed to raw console output or `View()` which is impractical for long strings (e.g. many paragraphs)

Comment: If you run `DT::datatable(mydata)` Your `mydata` data frame will be displayed in RStudio's viewer tab for a more comfortable viewing. You can also have it displayed on a separate browser page if you need more screen real estate. Would that help?

Comment: @Phil works perfectly (even sensibly displays list columns; comma separated). Also: control + shift + 9 to zoom on viewer pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DT::datatable()` provides the ability to view raw data in tables using all the features of the Javascript DataTables library either in RStudio's viewer tab or separately on the browser of your choice. You can further finetune the display of your data to fit your needs using any of the features provided here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/